# How to convert JavaDoc into Markdown?

Tags: java, android, markdown, javadoc, android-library

I have an Android library fully written in Java which contains a bunch of comments that I can generate into JavaDoc and see in HTML format.

I would like to **find a way of either converting my JavaDoc into Markdown, or** straight up **generating Markdown from the comments in my Android library** project.

For reference, I've looked into [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/master/README.md), which only seems to works for Kotlin project, so that seems out of the equation.

Comment: Markdown is much less expressive than HTML and likely than JavaDoc, too. What do you hope to achieve by converting to Markdown?

Comment: @Chris in one word: versatility. To be more specific, we're trying to get all of the library's documentation into Markdown so that we can upload that to one of the many tools that host Markdown documentation, but do not support JavaDoc.  Regardless of expressiveness, JavaDoc generally doesn't play nice with other tools the same way Markdown does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use marklet lib to convert JavaDoc to markdown.[Marklet Github link](https://github.com/Faylixe/marklet).
You can configure it in your pom if you use maven

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <doclet>fr.faylixe.marklet.Marklet</doclet>
        <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>fr.faylixe</groupId>
            <artifactId>marklet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </docletArtifact>
        <reportOutputDirectory>./</reportOutputDirectory>
        <destDir>./</destDir>
        <additionalparam>-d javadoc/</additionalparam>
        <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This project doesn't seem to have much activity since 2018.  I submitted an issue on them, but would like to pose the same question to you: How would I integrate this to my Android Studio build process?  I've got no idea on how to properly manipulate POM files, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dokka` to output your javadoc directly into markdown (at least Github Flavored Markdown) (ref. https://medium.com/androiddevnotes/how-to-use-dokka-documentation-engine-for-android-gradle-to-generate-kdoc-or-javadoc-comments-2b5f177595ec)

`./gradlew clean app:dokkaGfm` and VIOLA!